# Ugettext_lazy as dictionary key in django

Tags: django

Why the following code doesn't work?

Is it possible to use proxy objects as keys?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

ABBREVIATIONS = {
    _('tr.'): 'transitive'
}
```

Comment: It should work, what is the error you get?

Comment: File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/ukr_tran/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use proxy objects.You have to cast the key to a valid type, for example to a string:

```
ABBREVIATIONS = {
    str(_('tr.')): 'transitive'
}
```